# Remove error message background color and error word

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

As the title says I wanna remove the background color from the error message alongside the Error word 
[image: Error message]

I've tried inspecting it in google chrome and changed some CSS code but nothing has changed, I managed to change the error color though but not to remove the red background-color and that {"error" : }

I want the error to be like this

> You must provide a valid email

this is my code

```
.error{
  color:red;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Html

```
 <v-row>
          <div class="error" v-html="error"/>
    </v-row>
```

Javascript

```
methods: {
    async register () {
      try {
        await AuthenticationService.register({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        })
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.response.data
      }
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE :** 
For the error message format, I managed to solve it by adding .error to the *error.response.data*

```
this.error = error.response.data.error
```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `error.response.data`? Try adding `console.log(typeof error.response.data, error.response.data)`. Also, use your browser's _Elements_ dev-tools tab to find out where the styles are coming from. There's not enough information in this question to provide an answer

Comment: that's what I did I tried inspecting it and inside the browser i can change the background-color of .v-application .error to transparent but when I try to apply that to my actual css code it doesn't work, am newbie to vue and frontend development in general so I may be missing something here

Comment: already did, probably the way I structured my question wasn't so clear so I am completely sorry for that, I changed it to .v-application .error and tried to change the color of the error message and it worked but the background-color not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/), try

```html
<div class="error--text">{{ error }}></div>
```

You won't need any custom CSS.